# Get Date from Regional Datetime string

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I want to fetch only date: 2013-09-24 from the following string using php:

```
$2013-09-24T11:53:58+02:00am09pam53119_Tue, 24 Sep 2013 11:53:58 +0200Europe/Berlin58000000Tuesday30[0]
```

I am getting above string from this line of code:

```
 $second_date =  date('$first_date[0]', strtotime("+15 days") );
```

Is there any php built-in function to do this or what can be the simplest way?

Comment: i hope i will never ever bump into this itgeek's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that weird string, then just use this

```
<?php    

$str = "$2013-09-24T11:53:58+02:00am09pam53119_Tue, 24 Sep 2013 11:53:58 +0200Europe/Berlin58000000Tuesday30[0]";
$pattern = '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class. You can even fetch time and timezone :

```
$str = "$2013-09-24T11:53:58+02:00am09pam531.....";
$dt = new DateTime(substr($str, 1, 25));

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
# 2013-09-24

print_r($dt);
/*
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2013-09-24 11:53:58
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +02:00
)
*/
```